# unable to locate package error on fedora

Tags: fedora

It is found that compat-libicu57 library has been removed from fedora 29 fresh installation. I have a program which depends on this package. How can I install compat-libicu57 package using any package management tool. I have tried to install with yum I am getting an error unable to locate package.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Fedora Package site](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/compat-libicu57/) there are RPMs for fc29 that can be downloaded even though it has been removed from distribution.

I suspect it would be better to migrate your current application to the newer ABI provided by libicu.